# Convolutional Autoencoder Not Training on (62,47,1) dataset, "Expected Shape Error"

Tags: python, keras, convolution, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a Convolutional Autoencoder on the Faces in The Wild Dataset, which is made up of images shaped 62x47x3.

However, the Keras Convolutional Autoencoder example on the mnist dataset is not working with this new dataset I'm training on.

It throws this error

```
Error when checking target: expected conv2d_102 to have shape (60, 44, 3) but got array with shape (62, 47, 3)
```

about a certain layer receiving the wrong shape input, even after including the

```
padding='same'
```

commands that are supposed to make the input and output shapes equal.

I've tried only using grayscale images in the network but that doesn't make a difference.

Here is the main code I'm working with

```
import tensorflow
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Input, Reshape, Flatten, Deconvolution2D, Conv2DTranspose, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.optimizers import adam

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#importing the dataset in color cause that's dope
lfw_data = fetch_lfw_people(color=True)

#putting the data of images into a variable
x = lfw_data.images

#making a train and validation set
(x_train,x_test) = train_test_split(x, test_size=0.25)

#normalizing the pixel values
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

print(x_train.shape)

x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train), 62,47,3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(len(x_test), 62,47,3)

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

input_img = Input(shape=(62, 47, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.summary()
```

and the model summary output is

```
Model: "model_14"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_18 (InputLayer)        (None, 62, 47, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_103 (Conv2D)          (None, 62, 47, 16)        448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_45 (MaxPooling (None, 31, 24, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_104 (Conv2D)          (None, 31, 24, 8)         1160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_46 (MaxPooling (None, 16, 12, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_105 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 12, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_47 (MaxPooling (None, 8, 6, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_106 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 6, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_42 (UpSampling (None, 16, 12, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_107 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 12, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_43 (UpSampling (None, 32, 24, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_108 (Conv2D)          (None, 30, 22, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_44 (UpSampling (None, 60, 44, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_109 (Conv2D)          (None, 60, 44, 1)         145       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,673
Trainable params: 4,673
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________
```

When I try to train

```
#train for 100 epochs
history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs=100,batch_size=256, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

I get this error message

```
Error when checking target: expected conv2d_102 to have shape (60, 44, 3) but got array with shape (62, 47, 3)
```

Any help or explanation as to why it's throwing this error would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the poolings and paddings that are not matching. 
Your data has shape `(62,47)`, but your model outputs `(60,44)`. You need to adjust the model or the data properly.

Based on how pooling works (divide by 2), and considering you have 3 poolings, your image size will only match the poolings correctly if its a multiple of 2^3 = 8. Since the sizes 64 and 48 are very near the sizes of your images, it seems that the simplest solution would be to add padding to the images.

So, make your data have size `(64,48)`. - This will allow up to 4 poolings without any need for custom paddings in the model.

```
x_train = np.pad(x_train, ((0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0)), mode='constant')
x_test = np.pad(x_test, ((0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0)), mode='constant')
```

Don't forget to set `padding='same'` to **all** layers. There is one convolution that misses it (the one before the last)

Perhaps some of the modes listed [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) may perform better than others. (I'd try the `mode='edge'`, for instance.)

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, when I add the 2 lines you have above to pad arrays I get the following error message. "operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2) and requested shape (4,2)" Not sure what this is as I've never gotten something like this before when padding

Comment: Hmmm, you probably need the batch dimension too, like `((0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0))`. The images are probably 4D `(batch, size1, size2, channels)`. - See updated answer.